# Singular Value Decomposition vs iterative Methods for solving inverse Problems

Tags: inverse, least-squares, svd, inverse-problems

Background: I am trying to motivate why I use an SVD instead of an iterative LMS solver for the solution of an equation of the form

$$Ax=b$$

where $A\in\mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$,$x\in\mathbb{C}^{M}$ and $b\in\mathbb{C}^{M}$ and $x$ is unkown. The literature I have read states that a SVD is "numerically robust" (whatever that means) without specifying it further. As far as I understand, the LMS solver also converges to the optimal solution provided by using the SVD but can be slow if the eigenvalue distribution of $A$ is high.

Question: What advantages does the solution of the inverse problem using SVD offer over iterative LMS solvers?

Comment: I think many people don't know the acronym "LMS". I looked it up and it means "least mean squares". There are several different iterative methods available for solving least squares problems. A rule of thumb is that iterative methods for solving $Ax = b$ are useful when $A$ is so large that the $O(n^3)$ cost of solving $Ax = b$ via a direct method (such as LU factorization or QR factorization) is prohibitively expensive. Iterative methods can quickly find an approximate solution (at least, if $A$ is sufficiently well conditioned), and sometimes a good approximate solution is all you need.

Comment: Why then is the calculation path via LU or QR taken at all if $A$ is well conditioned? I understand why iterative methods are used but not the other way around.

Comment: Regarding the meaning of "numerically robust": numerical algorithms never find the exact solution due to roundoff errors. Some numerical algorithms are "unstable" which means that roundoff errors can be amplified, resulting in a solution that has low precision. A "stable" numerical algorithm is one that is not very sensitive to roundoff error.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the answer to why direct methods are usually preferred when $A$ is small or medium sized is probably a combination of the following: 1) Better (or at least not worse) operation count for direct methods (assuming we want an "exact" rather than an approximate solution); 2) Direct methods are more numerically stable; 3) Direct methods can be implemented in a way that makes better use of computer hardware, like GPUs or vector processing units. 4) Direct methods are easier to understand. If any of this is incorrect, hopefully someone will correct me.